# TeamCity not copying Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, teamcity

I have Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll referenced in my project, which lies inside my lib folder and has it's property set to Copy Local=true in visual studio 2008. When I build my project both in release & debug mode, the library is copied to the output.However when TeamCity runs the build, I cannot find the library in the output.Any specific reasons why this could be happening?

Note that my teamcity server has Office2007 installed wherin my dev machine has office2003 installed.

Also could you please suggest some ways to overcome this issue?

Thanks,
-M

Comment: Have you tried building your project manually on the build machine?

Comment: I just did it, and saw that Copy Local is set to false on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll inside VS2008 solution, does VS2008 changes this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing Office on your machine... Or remove those from Windows cache assemblies

Comment: Why would this work?  Isn't the problem that TeamCity lacks the DLLs in the same location as the dev machine?  And shouldn't the fix be including the DLL with the project (or via NuGet?)